# Android Studio Reformat Comment

Tags: android-studio, coding-style, comments, code-formatting

How can we make autoformatting convert **single line comments** from this

```
/**
 * My sample comment
 */
```

to

```
/** My sample comment */
```

Comment: Still didn't find out? ...Autocorrection to first form is really annoying when inline form would be much more lucid.